# How to force Doctrine2/Symfony2 getters to fetch updated data?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's consider a code like below in symfony2 command. I am using this dummy code just for testing my scenario:

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine")->getManager();

$user = $em->getRepository('FOSUserBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('username' => 'admin'));

do
{
    echo $user->getFirstname(); // How to force getFirstname to fetch the updated value?
    sleep(3);
}
while(true);
```

My question is why if I change the user `Firstname` in database, `echo` will still show the old `Firstname` and I have to restart the script to show the new `Firstname`.

How can I force `$user->getFirstname();` get and fetch updated data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the same code you have, assuming you still have the entity manager `$em` try this

```
$em->refresh($user)
```